# NiMH Pack won’t stay charged

Tags: batteries

I’m a total newbie at this and I need some help. I searched on Google and asked all these other sites. I couldn’t find what I was looking for. Well, I have a venom 8.4 V 3000 mAh pack that won’t hold a charge for very long. I examined the pack and I couldn’t find any damage or something noticeable. I would like to learn how to diy (do it myself), but don't want to damage it more or, even worse, injure myself. Please help!!

I’ve looked on this [site](https://www.rctech.net/forum/electric-road/90621-new-nimh-packs-wont-charge-help.html). Like I said, I'm a newbie and some of the information I found here doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: please post links to your questions at the other sites, so that we are not duplicating efforts

Comment: Sorry I’m not sure how to copy links from other sites I do apologize for my level of skill

Comment: just paste the web address into your question

Comment: I’m just getting into rc cars an I have a few battery packs that are bad an would like to learn how to fix em without having to spend a whole bunch of money I’ve seen people on YouTube making/fixing packs but most of the videos are edited

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations like "dnt". They don't exist in English and make reading your question unnecessarily hard. Also, don't beg! You're asking on a page that is run by volunteers, anyway, so begging doesn't help. I'm removing all the meaningless phrases from your question, as that cruft just reduces the quality of it.

Comment: So, what is "very long" in your terms? Months? Weeks? Hours? Minutes? What do you want to learn to do yourself? What exactly did you not understand? Please understand that this is a "Questions And Answers" site, so it's your job to come up with a precise question!

Comment: Even if you don’t notice that something is wrong by looking at it, doesn’t mean that there isn’t something wrong with the device because something is clearly wrong otherwise you wouldn’t be asking this question. Let’s try to troubleshoot this with deductive reasoning and process of elimination. What made the device malfunction? Did you try other battery packs? Did you accidentally damage your RC? When did you notice that something was wrong? Etc... Root cause analysis is like playing Sherlock Holmes for your device.

Answer (score 3):

The chances are that one or more of the cells is failing and self-discharging.

You would have to:

- Charge the pack and then wait for the voltage to drop.
- Un-package the battery pack so you can get at the individual cells.
- Use a voltmeter to find which cells have a lower voltage than the others.
- Source new cells of the same amp-hour rating.
- Disconnect the faulty cells and replace with new ones.  With any luck they will be soldered together.
- Package it all back up again.

Don't mix cells of different amp-hour ratings, as it will damage the lower rated cells.

Or just throw the whole thing in the (recycling) bin, and buy a new battery pack.